# Apache hangs/times out when backing up website with gzip or zip?

Tags: apache, process, timeout, gzip

I'm running some websites on a dedicated Ubuntu web server. If I'm remembering correctly, it has 8 cores, 16GB memory, and running as a 64 bit Ubuntu. Content and files are delivered quickly to web browsers. Everything seems like a dream... until I run gzip or zip to backup an 8.6GB sized website.

When running gzip or zip, Apache stops delivering content. Internal server error messages are delivered until the compression process is complete. During the process, I can login via ssh without delays and run the top command. I can see that the zip process is taking about 50% CPU (I'm guessing that's 50% of a single CPU, not all 8?).

At first I thought this could be a log issue, with Apache logs growing out of control and not wanting to be messed with. Log files are under 5MB though and being rotated when they hit 5MB. Another current thought is that Apache only wants to run on one CPU and lets any other process take the lead. Not sure where to look to address that yet.

Any thoughts on how to troubleshoot this issue? Taking out all my sites while backups occur is not an option, and I can't seem to reproduce this issue on my local machines (granted, it's different hardware and configuration). My hopes are that this question is not to vague. I'm happy to provide additional details as needed.

Thanks for your brains in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest running your backup script under the "ionice" command. It will help prevent starving httpd from I/O.

Comment: I'll mark this as the answer as that backs up what I'm finding elsewhere. I was still having some issues, but it turns out it could be related to hard drive speed. Upgrading the hard drive may be the next step. Until then, I'm planning on using rsync with another server to keep things backed up for quick access.